# How to automate incrementing variable & versionCode using fastlane android?

Tags: android, gradle, build-automation, fastlane, automated-deployment

I am using fastlane for automating apk. I've got a query here

How to check some conditions in the lane before assembling apk?

Ex: Whenever I run lane command for build apk I want to check with room DB version if the version is old then auto-increment it, change a value in code & build apk.

I'm trying to change the variable value too & change the versionCode of the apk. Thanks :)